# How to display 3 2 1 text in the center of the screen in transparency form

Tags: java, android, textview

I am working on a game.I have an AlertDialog for exit the game but when i press cancle button ao alertDialog my game stop for 3 seconds and resume again. i have implement this code but the text is not visible in center of the screen.
i thing which i want is when i press cancle button  3 2 1 text show on the screen and after display 1 text is invisible and game starts again.
here's my code

```
public class Game extends Activity {

MediaPlayer backgroungMusic;
Toast toast;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //   setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);



    //turn title off
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // set full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

    backgroungMusic = MediaPlayer.create(Game.this, R.raw.music);
    backgroungMusic.setLooping(true);
    backgroungMusic.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{

    super.onPause();
    backgroungMusic.release();
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


        //  GamePanel.thread.setStoped(true);
        GamePanel.thread.setRunning(false);
        // in the next line of code we also style the dialog through xml which i put in styles
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.myBackgroundStyle).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Exit Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you really want to exit the Game?");
        alertDialog.setButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Best way is firstly use finish() and after that use System.exit(0) to clear static variables. It will give you some free space.
                // A lot of applications leave working processes and variables what makes me angry. After 30 minutes of using memory is full and i have to run Task Manager - Lvl 2 clear memory
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
                return;

            }
        });



        alertDialog.setButton2("Cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // dialog.cancel();
                        // GamePanel.thread.resume();
                      // When user press the "Cancle" button then game resume for 3 seconds then start again
                   //     dialog.dismiss();
                        // Here is the Code of the toasts and each toast appear with delay of one second.

                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView123);
                        final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(3);
                        final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                          if(n.getAndDecrement() >= 1 )
                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                                else {
                                             GamePanel.thread.setRunning(true);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        handler.postDelayed(counter, 1000);

                        return;
                    }
                }

        );


        alertDialog.show();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And here's textview in xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Game">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView123"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:textSize="50dp" />
```

please help me thanks!

Comment: `the text is not visible` ... **where** do you set the text, **if** you do?

Comment: you need to use setText. example textview.setText(timer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to do `dialog.dismiss();`

You also have the problem that `final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView123);` is looking for a view on the dialog rather than on the activity where it lives, are there no erros in your `Logcat`? You need to be calling `textView.setText` at some point, but I would expect you to get a `NullPointerException`

What I would do is use a callback to the activity, it's best to do that by creating a DialogFragment.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
        MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.myBackgroundStyle);
        builder.setTitle("Exit Alert");
        builder.setMessage("Do you really want to exit the Game?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                if (getActivity() instanceof DialogClickListener) {
                    ((DialogClickListener) getActivity()).onPositive();
                }
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}

public interface DialogClickListener {
    void onPositive();
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements DialogClickListener {

    private TextView textView; //rename this

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView123);
    }

    public void showExitDialog() {
         FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
         MyDialogFragment exitDlg = (MyDialogFragment) fm.findFragmetByTag(MyDialogFragment.TAG);
         if (exitDlg != null && exitDlg.isAdded()) {
             exitDlg.dismiss();
         }
         exitDlg = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
         exitDlg.show(fm, AddEditDialogFragment.TAG);
    }

    public void onPositive() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(3);
        final Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (n.getAndDecrement() >= 1 ) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                } else {
                    GamePanel.thread.setRunning(true);
                }
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(n));
            }
         };
         handler.postDelayed(counter, 1000);
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            showExitDialog()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nick Cardoso i am waiting for your reply please hlep me thanks

Comment: Nick thanks for this. i update the code of my main activity please give me solution accourding to it . i am very thankfull to you.

Comment: I've literally already posted it. You can use the code in my example. Just add your alert dialog builder code to the builder in onCreateDialog and the rest you can copy and paste

Comment: Nick i am really sorry i distrub you again and again.Because i am new in android i cant understand what are you saying please edit my code accourding to my need thanks again.

Comment: Hi! Nick I add my alertDialog builder code to the builder in onCreateDialog but i got some errors i thinks its not properly added please tell me how i add properly in onCreateDialog if you tell me by edit code its better for me thanks.

Comment: I dont know what you want. I have literally posted the entire solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86676/discussion-between-mirza-zeeshan-and-nick-cardoso).

Answer (score -1):

In a RelativeLayout you can use centerInParent:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView123"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:textSize="50dp" />
```

Comment: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` is equivalent to `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"` so unfortunately won't solve the problem